# Overwriting a file without the risk of a corrupt file

Tags: c++, linux, windows, file-io

So often my applications want to save files to load again later. Having recently got unlucky with a crash, I want to write the operation in such a way that I am guaranteed to either have the new data, or the original data, but no a corrupted mess.

My first idea was to do something along the lines of (to save a file called example.dat):

1. Come up with a unique file name for the target directory, e.g. example.dat.tmp
2. Create that file and write my data to it.
3. Delete the original file (example.dat)
4. Rename ("Move") the temp file to where the original was (example.dat.tmp -> example.dat).

Then at load time the application can follow the following rules:

- If no "example.dat" and no  "example.dat.tmp", first run / new project, so load in the defaults / create new file.
- If "example.dat" and no "example.dat.tmp", then load example.dat (normal load case)
- If "example.dat.tmp" exists offer the user the chance to potentially recover data. If "example.dat" also exists, do not overwrite it without explicit user constant.

However, having done a little research, I found that as well as OS caching which I may be able to override with the file flush methods, some disk drives still then cache internally and may even lie to the OS saying they are done, so 4. could complete, the write is not actually written, and if the system goes down I have lost my data...

I am not sure the disk problem is actually solvable by an application, but are the general rules above the correct thing to do? Should I keep an old recovery copy of the file for longer to be sure, what are the guidelines regarding such things (e.g. acceptable disk usage, should the user choose, where to put such files, etc.).

Also how should I avoid potential conflict the user and other programs for "example.dat.tmp". I recall seeing a "~example.dat" sometimes from some other software, is that a better convention?

Comment: No need to delete the old file before renaming it. And that way is very common (writing to a temporary file, then renaming the temporary file as the original).

Comment: Having some check data in the file itself would let you verify its integrity.  In that case you could automatically handle the "both files exist" case -- if checking the tmp file shows that it is not corrupt then use it, otherwise use the dat file.  You can use the `FILE_FLAG_WRITE_THROUGH` flag when opening the file to bypass the write cache.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg But you'll usually want to rename the target with a `".bak"` first.

Comment: @cdhowie Is that sufficient? The documentation seems to indicate that it's not, but doesn't indicate what else is needed.  (The Windows documentation seems to indicate that it is the equivalent of `O_DSYNC` under Unix, but for full integrity, you need `O_DSYNC | O_SYNC`.)

Comment: @JamesKanze [This page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc644950%28VS.85%29.aspx) might be helpful.

Comment: @cdhowie Not really.  The problem is that a file isn't just the data in the file, it is also control information, which tells the system the size of the file, etc.  And for transactional integrity, that must be written through each time it changes as well.  (Since he's only concerned about the whole file, and not partial writes, a call to `fsync(fd)` just before closing the file would work on some Unices, including Solaris and Linux---Posix only requires it if `_POSIX_SYCHRONIZED_ID` is defined.)

Comment: On window's disabling the cache for the file, or calling FlushFileBuffers looks like it does the trick, and also should tell the disk drive to flush its buffers. My concern there was that hard disks are known to lie about the last bit and tell the OS it is done however thinking about it if the user is that unlucky I guess there just as likely to corrupt the FS itself than my file here? http://brad.livejournal.com/2116715.html http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2013/04/16/10411267.aspx#10411500

Comment: @cdhowie Thats a good idea. As it happens newer versions of the file format (i.e. some value at the start of the file >= x)use zlib to compress the rest of the file after the header, which I believe does a CRC type thing already. Will check, not too hard to make a new version and add in a checksum if not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the disk drives report back to the OS that the data is
physically on the disk, and it's not, then there's not much you
can do about it.  A lot of disks do cache a certain number of
writes, and report them done, but such disks *should* have
a battery backup, and finish the physical writes no matter what
(and they won't loose data in case of a system crash, since they
won't even see it).

For the rest, you say you've done some research, so you no doubt
know that you can't use `std::ofstream` (nor `FILE*`) for this;
you have to do the actual writes at the system level, and open
the files with special attributes for them to ensure full
synchronization.  Otherwise, the operations can stick around in
the OS buffering for a while.  And that as far as I know,
there's no way of ensuring such synchronization for a `rename`.
(But I'm not sure that it's necessary, if you always keep two
versions: my usual convention in such cases is to write to
a file `"example.dat.new"`, then when I'm done writing, delete
any file named `"example.dat.bak"`, rename `"example.dat"` to
`"example.dat.bak"`, and then rename `"example.dat.new"` to
`"example.dat"`.  Given this, you should be able to figure out
what did or did not happen, and find the correct file
(interactively, if need be, or insert an initial line with the
timestamp).

Comment: Pretty sure most disks cache and don't have a battery. Hence the warning on "Turn off Windows write-cache buffer flushing on the device", which comes back to some disk drives might lie about actually doing that.

Comment: I think the .bak idea helps make it clearer in the recovery situation. So all I really want now is a "did you really finish getting the new example.dat to disk, and not in some internal cache?" before deleting the bak file. I guess waiting a couple of minutes should be safe for basically every disk, perhaps even without the OS flushing commands. That leaves the really complicated solutions to the filesystem and database type things (since rewriting a multi-gb file on an insert/update/etc is likely not a practical thing to do).

Comment: @WillNewbery The disks I know that cache _do_ have a battery, and _do_ guarantee that all writes that have been acknowledged by the disk are persistent.  If this is not the case, you simply cannot use the disk in a professional context.

Comment: @WillNewbery Yes, the data was physically on disk.  This is guaranteed by Posix, and works on all professional systems I've worked on.

Comment: @WillNewbery And of course, you _don't_ write in the middle of a data set; your writes are to a journal file, which will permit reconstructing the data file from a backup if anything goes wrong.

Comment: Well, afaik most desktop and laptop SATA drives have no battery, and most seem to advertise cache space and is a good chance that's what end-users are going to have. I did look quickly at the server drives here, and they either have no cache or don't clearly advertise it (I guess at least some, or at least raid cards do for livejournal to have had their issue). I tried killing power to a test workstation (has some £30 drive with 16MB cache) a few times and the mutli-file write and rename never broke, so if it is possible at least it seems a small enough chance not to be a major concern.

Answer (score 0):

You should lock the actual data file while you write its substitute, if there's a chance that a different process could be going through the same protocol that you are describing.

You can use `flock` for the file lock.

As for your temp file name, you could make your process ID part of it, for instance "example.dat.3124,"   No other simultaneously-running process would generate the same name.

Comment: This doesn't address the question asked.

Comment: Actually, it does.  The title of the OP is "Overwriting a file without the risk of a corrupt file."  The protocol that the poster proposed would work, except for the possibility of overlapping processes executing it simultaneously.

Comment: Actually, it doesn't.  The OP was quite clear that his problem wasn't simultaneous writes, but the OS crashing in the middle of a write.

Comment: Well getting exclusive write access to some file is not such a problem. as for using the process ID to get a file name, what about in the event that it does crash, am I meant to then search for an "example.dat.*" when loading to see if there is something that might be my app?

Comment: @WillNewbery   That was presuming that parallel access to the data file that you are trying to protect was an issue (it appears not, but you would be the guy to ask).  Because Linux hosts databases, and large critical ones, there *has* to be a system call to disable write-through caching to the disk:  or else the OS would be an inadequate platform for hosting a transactional DB.  Without some way of guaranteeing that your "pre-image" is actually physically complete on disk, there will be no absolutely safe method.   I'm googling for answers, but without much luck...